# Is there a Google service that will return lat, lng info based on zipcode?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

I've looked at the [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) API from Google but they specifically state:

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google
>   map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

Does Google offer a service that will return lat, lng coordinates along with the town and state for a given zip code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is you want

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=302001&sensor=false

here 302001 is the postcode. This will give you the city country, latitude and longitude, a formatted address.

Comment: I don't think Google allows this correct, if the results are not used in conjunction with a map?

Comment: i use this in many of my works to get the latitude longitude and addresses. And google allows this. No harms to use.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are a [bunch of other services](https://www.google.com/search?q=geocode+web+service&oq=geocode+web+service) that let you do so.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this website](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/)  for when I have to do a lot of geocoding.